# Get name column instead of ids from two foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I need to get both group names as a result, although I have no idea how to do this query.

**Table 1 (groups)**

```
+---------+--------+
| id      | name   |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | newb   |
| 2       | user   |
| 3       | editor |
| 4       | boss   |
+---------+--------+
```

**Table 2 (inheritance)**

gid = group id; pid = parent id

```
+---------+--------+
| gid     | pid    |
+---------+--------+
| 3       | 1      |
| 3       | 2      |
| 4       | 1      |
| 4       | 2      |
| 4       | 3      |
+---------+--------+
```

**Expected Results**

Now I want the names of the groups as a result, not the ids, so I need to get this result:

```
+---------+--------+
| gname   | pname  |
+---------+--------+
| editor  | newb   |
| editor  | user   |
| boss    | newb   |
| boss    | user   |
| boss    | editor |
+---------+--------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 2 copies of names table:

```
SELECT groups_1.name AS gname, groups_2.name AS pname
FROM inheritance
JOIN groups AS groups_1 ON inheritance.gid = groups_1.id
JOIN groups AS groups_2 ON inheritance.pid = groups_2.id
```